# Phoenix 1.1.4 issue with Brunch

Tags: npm, elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch

Trying to start new Elixir/Phoenix project. Can't get past that error:

```
▶ mix phoenix.server
[info] Running Test.Endpoint with Cowboy using http on port 4000
05 Feb 16:32:57 - error: Initialization error - You probably need to execute `npm install` to install brunch plugins. Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/helpers/interop-require-default'
  at /home/vagrant/test/node_modules/brunch/lib/plugins.js:103:17
  at Array.map (native)
  at deps.filter.dependency.map (/home/vagrant/test/node_modules/brunch/lib/plugins.js:91:8)
  at packages.filter.plugin.filter.plugins.map.plugin.filter.deps.filter.allPlugins.filter (/home/vagrant/test/node_modules/brunch/lib/plugins.js:110:19)
  at Object.packages.filter.plugin.filter.plugins.map.plugin.filter.deps.filter.exports.init.teardownBrunch [as init] (/home/vagrant/test/node_modules/brunch/lib/plugins.js:133:20)
  at /home/vagrant/test/node_modules/brunch/lib/watch.js:81:19
```

Versions:

- **machine**: Ubuntu 14.04 on Vagrant 1.7.4
- **node -v** : v4.2.6
- **npm -v** : 2.14.12
- **mix -v** : Mix 1.2.0
- **elixir -v** : Elixir 1.2.0
- **erlang** : 18
- **phoenix** : 1.1.4

Contents of projects **package.json**:

```
{
  "repository": {
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-brunch": "~6.0.0",
    "brunch": "~2.1.3",
    "clean-css-brunch": "~1.8.0",
    "css-brunch": "~1.7.0",
    "javascript-brunch": "~1.8.0",
    "uglify-js-brunch": "~1.7.0",
    "phoenix": "file:deps/phoenix",
    "phoenix_html": "file:deps/phoenix_html"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently now Elixir requires node.js >=5.0.0

> We can get node.js from the download page. When selecting a package to
>   download, it's important to note that Phoenix requires **version 5.0.0
>   or greater**.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
rm node_modules -r
npm install .
```

Fixed the problem